# Jquery getJSON function not giving alert

Tags: jquery, json

i have page call CustomerJASON.aspx which have a code like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MakeJasonCustomer();
        Request.ContentType = "application/json";
        var customer = new Customer()
        {
            ID = int.Parse(Request["id"]),
            FirstName = "Haseeb",
            LastName = "Khan"
        };
        var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Customer));
        jsonSerializer.WriteObject(Response.OutputStream, customer);
    }
```

i call this page using jQuery getjason function and the code which i write is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    LoadData();
});


function LoadData() {

    $('#SubmitButton').click(function () {

        $.getJSON('CustomerJASON.aspx', { id: 5 }, function (data) {
            alert(data.FirstName);

        });
    });
```

}

but the problem is i am not able to get alert from the getJSON function plz help me i am totally stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a console.log or console.dir to the code on data to make sure it is actually an object since if it is not alerting either it is not being called or the data.firstName is not correct and javascript is failing

```
console.dir(data);
alert(data.firstName);
```

Check in firebug or another tool what data is being shown

Answer (score 0):

You can add another WebMethod in the 'CustomerJASON.aspx' to handle the return value instead of the Page Load event

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string LoadData() { //Code Here }
```

and on the Javascript Code:

```
$.getJSON('CustomerJASON.aspx/LoadData', { id: 5 }, function (data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON()` does nothing if the ajax request fails. Open your **developer console** (F12, network tab) and check the response.

Alternatively, try attaching an error handler to see if what's happening.

```
$.getJSON('CustomerJASON.aspx', { id: 5 }, function (data) {
    alert(data.FirstName);
}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Inspect the values of jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown here.
});
```

Comment: my response is ok everything is good but my json is written on page i called but i am not getting any alert